# Returning results from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, one-to-many

I have Table A:

```
ID Name
```

Table B:

```
ID A_ID COLORS
```

A_ID is the FK to Table A
Table A to Table B is one to many.

I want to return all of Table B for a given Table A ID, in one SQL call.
I'm assuming this is the best idea, to return one result set in this scenario(?), then I'm going to scroll through the resultset to set all of the colors for a given person so I can set the color list.

```
Person(int id, String name, List<String>colors){

}
```

I trying to figure out the SQL, and I'm wondering in general if what I am doing is ok.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input data and the results that you want?

Comment: I'm going to make x number of Person objects. An example data set is Table A:(1, "Homer"), Table B:(1, 1, "Red"), (2, 1, "Blue"). This would make one Person object with id=1, name="Homer", and colors= ArrayList("Red", "Blue")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT TableA.Name, TableB.COLORS FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID=TableB.A_ID WHERE TableA.ID = "Given TableA ID"`

Depending on how many times you're running this query and how many results it is returning most likely returning them all in one shot is the right way to do it.

Comment: yeah, i'm looking how to get a single result set for all names and colors per name. then, in code, i would iterate and make the Person objects. I'm thinking its better to do one SQL call, than one per person?

Comment: Sounds like from what you just said, you want to just `SELECT * FROM Colors ORDER BY A_ID` and iterate that

Comment: i think that will work, thanks. How do i determine if I should just do one SQL, which will have duplicate data, or do one SQL per person?

Comment: Prefer one SQL unless it is a lot of data that will cause performance/memory problems on the client machine (usually this means 100K+ rows in a desktop application). Another reason to use multiple SQL statements is if much of the data will not be used. For example, you may display a list of all People but if it is unlikely for the user to click on most of the people and thus actually need the the colors, you might consider avoiding the one big SQL only pull the colors back in the (unlikely) event they're needed. In short, I'd use one SQL and then measure and see if you have problems.